# pytest- creating a plugin

Tags: python-3.x, testing, plugins, pytest

I would like to create pytest plugin, that includes hook function and fixtures.
I have created it locally on a conftest.py file located at my root folder, and everything works fine. Now I would like to use this code in other projects, by converting the conftest.py code into a pytest- plugin.
In theory I know I simply need to create a package, however I have some really hard time understanding the entry points that I will use for this plugin.

I have an approximation of what I need, where my actual code goes inside the metadata of the test and reports it to a file.

The example code:

conftest.py

```
@pytest.fixture(scope = 'function')
def upload_manager():
    def wrapper(val):
        # Do something
        return val
    return wrapper

def pytest_report_teststatus(report):
    if report.when == 'call':
        # Do something
    if report.when == 'setup':
        # Do something
```

test_foo.py

```
def test_bar(upload_manager):
    my_val = upload_manager(1000)
    assert my_val == 1000
```

How would I go about using this code (fixture and hooks) as a package?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, found an answer- This requires in the setup.py file to add the following key:

```py
entry_points={
        "pytest11": [
            "name_of_plugin = package.file_name",
        ],
    },
```

I've used it for a python plugin I wrote to extract data and metadata out of the tests themselves, it can be found here for future reference [pytest-data-extractor](https://github.com/Maxim-Mushizky/pytest-data-extractor).
If for some reason, someone needs it as package it can by installed directly from PyPi:

```
pip install pytest-data-extractor
```